# Checking if a character entry in a function is in set of vectors in R

Tags: r

Please, I am trying to print a message based on an entry of a user.
I am studying for a test and I want to create a function that If I type an specific article( variable character) It will check over a set of vectors and print a message.

```
ExpfromUS <- function(x){
  x <- readline("Check if your articles could be import or export to US. Entry the type of article that you want to ship:   ")
  a <- c(x == CBOExUS)
  b <- c(x == RQSVExUS)
  e <- c(x == NATExUS)
   for ( i in length(a == TRUE)){      
        if (a[i] == TRUE){
        print("Ok, but just with Contractual basis only");
              break; }
        else{ for (i in length(b)){
              if (b[i] == TRUE){
              print("Ok, but with restrictions of quantity, size or value");
                    break;}
              else{ for (i in length(c)){
                    if (e[i] == TRUE){
                    print("Sorry, but we are not able to ship your cargo at this moment");
                          break;}
                    else{ print("Please check your entry we could not find this article in our database")
                          }}
              }
              }

        }
  }
```

}

But always print the last message "Please check your entry we could not find this article in our database", what am I doing wrong? (Sorry this is a beginner level doubt).
Thanks for all who spend their time helping me.

Comment: How exactly are you calling `ExpfromUS()`? What are you passing in? Are values like `CBOExUS` variables that are defined elsewhere?

Comment: `length(a == TRUE)` will always be the same as `length(a)` and will be  single integer. Perhaps you were expecting what `which(a)` would have returned. (No need for the `== TRUE`)

Comment: Are those odd-named objects (`CBOExUS` and friends) defined somewhere, or are they meant to be strings (`x == "CBOExUS"`)? If they are defined in the global or calling environment, it is bad practice to have this function require those exist elsewhere, and this function will produce results that are not guaranteed to be reproducible.

Comment: I have CBOExUS and the others in my global Enviroment

Answer (score 0):

Expanding my comment: I suspect that your indexing for all the `for` loops is (part) the problem. The current indexing is only going to cause one iteration since `length(a == TRUE)` will return a single integer. I suspect you wanted the numeric values where "a == TRUE" so you could output a message at that row. The `which` function returns numeric values corresponding to the index of "TRUE" values of a logical vector, so perhaps you wanted:

```
    for ( i in which(a) ){   
           ....}
           else{ for (i in which(b)){
                ...}
               else{ for (i in which(c)){
                     ....}
```

Further note: When working with logical vectors it is rarely necessary to include  `== TRUE` and is sometimes going to return unexpected results when the vector includes NA's, since NA is never `==` to anything.

Given what you have offered as values for those three vectors I now thin it should have been

```
 {....
  a <-  x %in% CBOExUS  # the c() not needed. This returns a logical vector
  b <-  x %in% RQSVExUS
  e <-  x %in% NATExUS
  .....
```

THe `%in%` function allows you to test for multiple values. The `==` function is asking if there is complete equality, obviously unlikely. There **still** may these correction be other flaws, but we're *still* without a [MCVE] and so we *still* won't be able to offer tested coding.

Comment: Thank you 42-. After your recommendations I put: `CBOExUS <- c("Alcoholic beverages","Dangerous goods" ,"Diagnostic specimens","Perishables","Personal effects","Plants","Seeds","Tobacco")
      RQSVExUS <- c("Airline Tickets", "Ammunition", "Artwork","Dangerous Goods","Knives","Loose Gemstones","Loose Pearls","Magnets","Precious Metals") 
      NATExUS <- c("Animal products,non-domesticated", "Cash", "Corpses", "Firearms", "Human Remains","Industrial Diamonds","Ivory","Letters of Credit Shipments","Live Animals","Pornographic Materials","Precious Stones","Postage Stamps")
  `

Comment: Inside the function. Take of realines and assigned a name that I want to check in a variable in the global enviroment. Change length for wich.  To the first list CBOExUS runs perfect, but for the elements that are inside RQSVExUS and NATExUS didn't work. You know why?